# How to insert object already existing objects in NSMutableArray list

Tags: objective-c, insert, nsmutablearray

I am getting a problem, while inserting an object into the main List.

```
[editContactList addObject:editcontacts];
[editObject.contactList insertObject:editContactList atIndex:0];//error as mutating method sent to immutable object
[editcontacts release];
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is there a compile-time error? A run-time error? What's wrong?

Comment: How to insert the objcet into the nsmutable array  from anthoer mutable array , i am getting run time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get that particular error, you don't actually have an `NSMutableArray`; you have an `NSArray`. Which is immutable. (Note that simply casting an `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` does nothing, the array itself needs to be an instance of a mutable array, rarely seen with instance variables, especially those made accessible publicly.)

**Edit:** We're going to need some more information; how are these variables defined, how are they initialized, etc.