# When I am replacing or inserting an object into nsmutable array, I am getting an Exception

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exception, nsmutablearray

While replacing or inserting into an `NSMutable` array, I am getting exception as:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

```
[list replaceObjectAtIndex:indexRow withObject:editcontacts];
//or

[list insertObject:editcontacts atIndex:indexRow];
```

Comment: Show a line where you create your list object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are still using an `NSArray` instead of an `NSMutableArray`. You need to allocate `list` as such:

```
NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712126/how-to-insert-object-already-existing-objects-in-nsmutablearray-list)